# Highlight minimum value in each row, ignoring zeros and skipping columns

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight the smallest value in *each* row using conditional formatting (CF), while ignoring zeros and blanks. Also, I don't want the ranges to be continuous (i.e. skipping certain columns).

For example, give the following sheet:

```
   A    B    C     D      E
1 345   0   skip  123  <empty>
2  0   211  skip  234  <empty>
```

I would like to have D1 and C2 highlighted, independently.

I can get part way by using a **custom formula** in CF:
`=A1=min({$A1,$B1,$D1,$E1})`

However I'm running into a couple of issues:

- Zeros and empty cells are highlighted (which I don't want)
- How to apply CF to each row independently without manually creating CF for each row (i.e. without having to do `=A2=min({$A2,$B2,$D2,$E2})`, `=A3=min({$A3,$B3,$D3,$E3})`, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another way to do it with a *single* CF formula using ArrayFormula:

`=A1=ArrayFormula((MIN(IF({$A1,$B1,$D1,$E1}>0,{A1,$B1,$D1,$E1}))))`

The key is to also Apply to Range:
`A1:A,B1:B,D1:D,E1:E`

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the entire range A2:D can be formatted in the specified way by using the custom formula

```
=and(column(A2) <> 3, A2 = min(filter({$A2,$B2,$D2}, {$A2,$B2,$D2} > 0)))
```

Which is a combination of two conditions:

- `column(A2) <> 3` says to not format column C
- `filter({$A2,$B2,$D2}, {$A2,$B2,$D2} > 0)` says to ignore the empty cells and zeros when finding the minimum. The value of current cell being equal to the minimum of these (`A2 = min(...)`) ensures in particular that it's not zero or blank itself.